# window.scrollBy not scrolling full width of screenn

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm really new to coding so please be gentle and keep your answers simple!

I'm trying to add a button that will scroll the page horizontally by the full-screen width, however, my code is scrolling about 20px short.

Does anyone know why? And the fix?

Many thanks - code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
       width: 400%;
    }
    button {
        position: fixed;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <button
        class="btn2", onclick="scrollWin((window.outerWidth), 0)">ᐅ</button><br><br>
<script>
    function scrollWin(x, y) {window.scrollBy(x, y);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the default margin set to the `body` tag. To set this margin back to 0,

```
body {
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

As it states in [W3 in schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp), the default margin set to the tag is 9 pixels, making it 18 pixels both wider and longer than desired, and thus complying with your statement,

> my code is scrolling about 20px short.

Also, to prevent the browser from occasionally ignoring your manual margin setup, an `!important` is required.

Results: [Click Here](https://fdsf.coderct.repl.co/)

Comment: I've added that in but it still isn't completely working. It has closed the margin slightly on about it is only about 10px short but on the final screen it is about 50px short. Could the position of my button or anything else be making a difference?

Comment: I don't know if allowed to post this - but here is the link so you can see what is happening http://businesshostinglifetimealisonelman-ss.stackstaging.com/?page_id=301

Comment: @ALiE try `overflow: hidden`

Comment: It's nearly there but still a bit out!